# Django web development prblem: blank=True and null=True but still can not create post without image field

Tags: python, django, web, imagefield

This is my upload location:

```
 def upload_location(instance, filename):
    file_path = 'blog/{author_id}/{title}-{filename}'.format(
                author_id=str(instance.author.id),title=str(instance.title), filename=filename)
    return file_path
```

This is my class:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title                   = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    body                    = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    image                   = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)
    date_published          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="date published")
    date_updated            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="date updated")
    author                  = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug                    = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The form:

```
class CreateBlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'image']
```

And the view:

```
def create_blog_view(request):

    context = {}

    user = request.user
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('must_authenticate')

    form = CreateBlogPostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        author = Account.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
        obj.author = author
        obj.save()
        form = CreateBlogPostForm()
        return redirect('home')

    context['form'] = form

    return render(request, "blog/create_blog.html", context)
```

The problem is that I don't know why the error This field is required appears when I try to publish a post on the website. Not only that but if I try to set a default picture it does not work either, basically blank=True and null=True don't do what they should have done and default="default.jpeg" does not do the trick of putting a default image from the beginning either. I don't know honestly why this happens, tried to change multiple things in the code and still did not work, as u can see I am pretty new to it... I gave all related code to this problem in my opinion but feel free to ask for any more if needed! Thanks a lot :3

Comment: Did you try to set the default value of the image field to None?

Comment: @JanGiacomelli nope I did not can you please specify where I should find that and insert it?

Comment: image                   = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True, default=None) in your model

Comment: @JanGiacomelli welp still did not do the trick

Comment: Try to also add field to form: image = forms.ImageField(required=False)